# error when commit, first time to push at github

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push

Initially, I wanted to delete 1 file, so I immediately deleted it via VS Code without `git rm`, because I didn't know how to delete it. After I committed it, suddenly this appeared.

I don't know how is it going please help me.

```
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    Draft Skripsi.docx
```

In VS Code:

[image: at vscode]

In Github:

[image: github]

How to push safely after solved?

Comment: You follow the directions.  `-m` wants your commit message.  `git commit -m "Delete the draft."`  There's nothing out of the ordinary here.  Just do a `push` when done.

Comment: The question is not clear. I don't see any errors in the `git status` output, it is saying that git recognizes that you deleted the file on your local copy, but it isn't committed yet, because your `git commit` command is incomplete. I don't see the purpose of the screenshot of the Github repo. Are you basically asking how to delete a file from a repo?

Comment: Please remove the third screenshot; it only creates confusion, nothing necessary is evident there.

Answer (score 0):

In the first picture, `git status` says, "Changes to be committed" and lists there your deleted file "Skripsi.docx".

In your second picure where is showing your IDE Visual Studio Code, I can see in the terminal output, that your `git commit` command contains errors.

So first of all, `git commit` your changes without errors and then `git push` it.